# Copying records into another file based on condition

Tags: shell-script

I have a file that has multiple records.
I have to copy those records that have a code '06' at a specific position, lets say, at position 19 and 20, into a another file. Records don't have any spaces in between.
How can I achieve this using a shell script?

Comment: If records "don't have any spaces in between", what's the record separator? I'm assuming by "records" you actually mean fields: the separate columns that make up one row of the file.

Comment: Record separator is a newline character.

Comment: OK. So by "position 19 and 20" you mean 19 and 20 characters into the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "position 19 and 20" refers to characters 19 and 20 of the line being equal to '06', you can do this in many ways:

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E '^.{18}06' your_file > new_file
```

This looks for lines having 18 characters after the beginning of the line followed by the two characters `06`.

---

Using Bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    code="${line:18:2}"
    [ "$code" == 06 ] && printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < your_file > new_file
```

---

Similar to the above but in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if substr($_,18,2) eq "06"' your_file > new_file
```

In both Bash and Perl, the first position of the string is position 0, so characters 19 and 20 are at positions 18 and 19 (start at position 18 and read 2 characters) in this scheme.

Comment: I have updated the question.
I need to copy these records to another file.

Comment: @RajWadhwa So use the output redirection part I added to the answer: either add `> new_file` or `>> new_file` at the end of whichever command you end up using and it's done.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts.
As I'm a novice to shell scripting, can you please tell me, whether this will work with .ksh also?

Comment: @RajWadhwa The `grep` and `perl` solutions will work irrespective of shell. I'm not sure that the Bash substring notation works in `ksh`.

Comment: @RajWadhwa OK, I tried the `bash` solution on `ksh` and it works fine so you should be able to use any of the 3 solutions on `ksh` with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am marking the answer as accepted. But I will try the solution later and will let you know. :) Thanks once again.

Comment: I tried for the grep solution but it gave an error that -E is an invalid option.

Comment: @ joseph.. perl solution worked thankss a lotttt.. :) :)

Comment: @joseph... and for bash solution it says..   ksh[3]: code="${line:17:2}": bad substitution Please suggest

Comment: @RajWadhwa This is really strange. Because the `-E` switch to `grep` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/grep.html) as for `ksh`, I tried the syntax on `ksh93` and it worked. What OS are you on? and what version of `ksh` do you use?